# How get id of html elements when it generates dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jsp

I create design for image, checkbox and drop-down list..  the image will create dynamically according to number of row..
My question is how can validate which checkbox was checked and which drop down option was selected because all of its have same id and name

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question according to recommendations

Answer (score -1):

First of all welcome to stackoverflow :D

If all of you checkboxes have the same ID it won't work. You said you create them dynamically then try to give them an special identifier like "myid"+i wehreas i being the number of the element (increase it after instantiating the element).
Then your IDs will look like:

myid0

myid1

myid2

...

with all the objects having a different ID it won't be a problem for you to check which checkbox was selected :)